# Grouping the array in php

Tags: php, arrays, regex, reference

Sample array values:

```
      Array ( [0] => '2014-07-04 ' [1] => 246 ) 
      Array ( [0] => '2014-07-04' [1] => 213 ) 
      Array ( [0] => '2014-07-04 ' [1] => 274 ) 
      Array ( [0] => '2014-07-04 ' [1] => 249 ) 
      Array ( [0] => '2014-07-04 ' [1] => 253 ) 
      Array ( [0] => '2014-07-04 ' [1] => 23 ) 
      Array ( [5] => '2014-07-04 ' [6] => 11) 
      Array ( [5] => '2014-08-04 ' [6] => 1743 ) 
      Array ( [5] => '2014-08-04 ' [6] => 1.31 ) 
      Array ( [5] => '2014-08-04' [6] => 172 ) 
      Array ( [5] => '2014-08-04 ' [6] => 179 ) 
      Array ( [5] => '2014-08-04 ' [6] => 1709 ) 
      Array ( [5] => '2014-08-04 ' [6] => 176 )
```

Now I want to separate this array into two array like below:

```
      Firstarray=>array(
      Array ( [0] => '2014-07-04 ' [1] => 246 ) 
      Array ( [0] => '2014-07-04' [1] => 213 ) 
      Array ( [0] => '2014-07-04 ' [1] => 274 ) 
      Array ( [0] => '2014-07-04 ' [1] => 249 ) 
      Array ( [0] => '2014-07-04 ' [1] => 253 ) 
      Array ( [0] => '2014-07-04 ' [1] => 23 ) 
      )

      Secondarray=>array(
      Array ( [5] => '2014-07-04 ' [6] => 11) 
      Array ( [5] => '2014-08-04 ' [6] => 1743 ) 
      Array ( [5] => '2014-08-04 ' [6] => 1.31 ) 
      Array ( [5] => '2014-08-04' [6] => 172 ) 
      Array ( [5] => '2014-08-04 ' [6] => 179 ) 
      Array ( [5] => '2014-08-04 ' [6] => 1709 ) 
      Array ( [5] => '2014-08-04 ' [6] => 176 ) 
      )
```

Please suggest some ideas. Help me to write a code in php. Main challenge is to splitting the array into two parts based in the index values.

Comment: Do you start with an array of arrays? If so, based on my best guess, you would iterate each element and check the key of the first element therein.

Comment: if you know the keys then it is already separate.

Comment: array values will be dynamically changed..some times index will comes like [0][1],[5][6],[10][11],[15][16]..So i need to create the generic function for grouping it into separate array

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: depth will be the same??

Comment: actually i am trying to read the data from text file and make this array.i want to grouping the array with indexes..depth also will varied

Comment: how are you fetching those data? and the date & the value are different items of the array?

Comment: yeah different items.it comes from text file.After removing the whitespace from the lines it will look like this array.[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915433/reading-text-file-using-php-and-create-dynamic-genric-parser)

Comment: I think you should do the split earlier on, before you add each line into an array.

Comment: Does a loop generate these arrays or how do these arrays get created?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work for you....

```
<?php
$combArray = array
(
    Array ( 0 => '2014-07-04', 1 => 246 ), 
    Array ( 0 => '2014-07-04', 1 => 213 ), 
    Array ( 0 => '2014-07-04', 1 => 274 ), 
    Array ( 0 => '2014-07-04', 1 => 249 ), 
    Array ( 0 => '2014-07-04', 1 => 253 ),
    Array ( 0 => '2014-07-04', 1 => 23  ), 
    Array ( 5 => '2014-07-04', 6 => 11  ), 
    Array ( 5 => '2014-08-04', 6 => 1743), 
    Array ( 5 => '2014-08-04', 6 => 1.31), 
    Array ( 5 => '2014-08-04', 6 => 172 ), 
    Array ( 5 => '2014-08-04', 6 => 179 ), 
    Array ( 5 => '2014-08-04', 6 => 1709), 
    Array ( 5 => '2014-08-04', 6 => 176 )
);

$tmpKey   = ''; 
$ResArray = array();    

$i=0;
foreach ($combArray as $arLoop) 
{
    $arkeys = array_keys($arLoop);

    if ($tmpKey != $arkeys[0]) 
    {
        $i++;
    }

    $ResArray[$i][] = $arLoop;

    $tmpKey = $arkeys[0];
}

print_r($ResArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this one...

```
   <?php

     $items = array(
           array(0 => '2014-07-04', 1 => 246),
           array(0 => '2014-07-04', 1 => 213),
           array(0 => '2014-07-04', 1 => 1500),
           array(5 => '2014-07-04', 6 => 11),
           array(5 => '2014-07-04', 6 => 112),
           array(5 => '2014-07-04', 6 => 23131),
           array(7 => '2014-07-04', 8 => 23131),
     );


      $results = [];
      foreach ($items as $element) {    
          grouper($element,$results);
      }

     function grouper(array $arr,array &$res)
     {
        static $group = 1;
        if (! array_key_exists($group, $res)) {
           $res[$group][] = $arr;
           return false;
        }

        if (isset($res[$group][array_keys($arr)[0]])){
           $res[$group][] = $arr;
        } else {
           $res[$group][] = $arr;
           $group++;
        }
     }

    echo '<pre>' , print_r($results,true) , '</pre>';
```